# Visual Studio : Create Entity Data Model with remote Mysql database

Tags: mysql, ado.net, remote-access, edmx

In my Wpf application (with C#, Visual Studio) I have two problems:

1. I tried to create an edmx model with a remote Mysql database in local network, I have the IP address and host name but when trying to make a new connection it doesn’t work.

I get a message box with:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

when I click on "Test Connection" and

> Unable to retrieve the list of databases

when clicking on Database name.

I tried with the IP shown in the image, also with hostname Amira-HP for example, I also added the port number 3306 but just nothing!

2. Actually the application is connected to a local MySql database, but when deploying  and installing it in another computer it doesn’t launch, even with a local Wamp server (with a local Mysql database).

I tried to ask google but didn't find an answer.

Comment: Is there an error message? Is there some relevant code you could put in your question?

Comment: Thanx for your answer, for the first question the error is a message box with : "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." when I click on "Test Connection" and "Unable to retrieve the list of databases" when  clicking on Database name.

Answer (score 1):

1- The problem was that it's not possible to create an edmx model with IP adress and user name root, so i created another MySql user account with a password.

2- There was some missing dll, so for every reference in my project i checked "copy local" to have a copy of every dll in the Debug directory where we find the .exe of the application.

Thanx for everyone, hope that that my answer helps you.